# Calculate the size of a string using inline assembler in C

Tags: c, assembly, inline-assembly

I am quite bad at assembly, but I currently have an assignment using C and inline assembly using the VS2015 x86 native compiler. I need to calculate the size of a string given by parameter. Here is my approach:

```
void calculateLength(unsigned char *entry)
{
    int res;
    __asm {
        mov esi, 0
        strLeng:
            cmp [entry+ esi], 0
            je breakLength
            inc esi
            jmp strLeng
        breakLength:
        dec esi
        mov res, esi
    }
    printf("%i", res);
}
```

My idea was to increment the esi registry until the null character was found but, every time I get 8 as a result.

Help is appreciated!

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I really don't get why is my return always 8

Comment: Maybe because you don't increment `eax` inside the loop? Or maybe because you used `esi` in the loop but didn't assign that to `eax` or `res`.

Comment: And now you are missing a `return res;` and also why do you have `unsigned char` return type.

Comment: Yes, I did notice that I edited the code to the correct one, still, the answer is 8

Comment: And how long is the string? :D Note that you don't need the `dec esi` either. Also `cmp [entry+esi]` is likely processing the pointer not the string pointed to. So before the loop load `entry` into a register, e.g. `mov ebx, [entry]` and then use `cmp [ebx+esi], 0`. And better make sure you use a byte comparison, so `cmp byte ptr [ebx+esi], 0`.

Comment: For every single string I input, it returns 8.

Comment: I changed the `cmp [entry+esi]` and it worked. So yeah, it was processing the pointer itself, not the string

Comment: @CatalinaCuellar Cool!  Write up your solution as an answer so I can upvote it!

Answer (score 5):

I will be posting the corrected code, thanks a lot Jester for sorting it out

```
void calculateLength(unsigned char *entry) {
    int res;
    __asm {
        mov esi, 0
        mov ebx, [entry]
        strLeng:
            cmp [ebx + esi], 0
            je breakLength
            inc esi
            jmp strLeng
        breakLength:
        mov res, esi
    }
    printf("%i", res);
}
```

What was happening was that `cmp [entry+ esi], 0` was comparing the pointer value + the index with zero and not the string content.

Comment: What's `entrada`?

Comment: @JL2210 Probably supposed to be `entry` but forgotten during copy-editing.